# How do I change Xcode Project Format to Xcode 3.2-compatible?

Tags: xcode

I am having problems with code completion and read that this will fix it but I don't know where this setting is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's highly unlikely that the project format has any bearing on code completion, but if you really want to change it, select the project itself in the file navigator and open the right-side utility pane. In the first tab is the project format drop down.

[image]

Comment: The only drop downs I have when I do this are "iOS Deployment Target" and "Command-line builds use"... no "Project Format".

Comment: Nevermind, I found it. I was looking the debug area and not the utilities.